# how can i create an array from another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create an array like this:

```
var routes: [{
  locations: [
    [40.749825, -73.090443],
    [42.743244, -71.594375],
    [37.058435, -74.903842]
  ],
  color: 'red',
  opacity: 1
}]
```

starting from this:

```
var locations: [
  {location: "40.749825, -73.090443"},
  {location: "42.743244, -71.594375"},
  {location: "37.058435, -74.903842"}
]
```

using javascript/jquery.
Can anybody help me please?

thank you

Comment: `locations.map((x) => x.location.split(", ").map(parseFloat))` for the hard part

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry I made a mistake, I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `color` and `opacity` properties as it is, and on the locatoins property use `map` method to `split` each string with `', '`

```js
var locations = [
  {location: "40.749825, -73.090443"},
  {location: "42.743244, -71.594375"},
  {location: "37.058435, -74.903842"}
]

const routes = [{
  color: 'red',
  opacity: 1
}]

routes[0].locations = locations.map(({ location }) => location.split(', '));

console.log(routes)
```